# Better way of repeatingly check a boolean value?

Tags: c++11

I have a class, that controls a process by calling multiple different methods. If something went wring inside these methods, then they will change a boolean value. When the value is changed, the controller should not call any further methods.
It currently looks like this:

```cpp
bool importantBool = true;

void doIt()
{
  if(importantBool)
  {
     doFirstThing();
  }
  if(importantBool)
  {
     doSecondThing();
  }
  if(importantBool)
  {
     doThirdThing();
  }
  //etc.pp.
}
```

Is there a way to stop this repeating call for my boolean and make this code easier to read (and write)?

Comment: Can you change these three functions to return something, like a bool?

Comment: It really depends on what code it is that you expect will clear your flag?
Globals are generally considered bad practice unless all other possibilities have been rejected during the design phase. If you are expecting these three functions to clear your flag, then they could take a reference to it as an ini-out non-const reference, or simply return the new flag. You may still prefer to write the if statements the way you have because they can be easier to step through in a debugger than the lazy evaluation of && and easier to see on the paper than a cascade of nested if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can make these functions return `bool` `false` on error and chain them with logical `and`:

```
doFirstThing() && doSecondThing() && doThirdThing();
```

Another way is to `throw` an exception on error from these functions (if that is truly an exceptional error).